# Best way to make relations between tables in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I can't find what is the good way to make relations between tables, should I create relations by `foreign` and `primary key`, something like `one-to-one, one-to-many` etc. Or I can use something like this and it will be having the same performance and the same speed of retrieve :

```
User                 PC
id name     age      id  name   bought_by
 1 Andrew   23        2   Asus      1
```

Comment: your two tables  seems not related .. try explain better and add  a proper sample ..

Comment: why not related if I store the id of the user in pc table, that means what this pc bought user with id 1.

Comment: In your sample  your PC table have not a column  id (user_id)  so the table are not related ..  anyway  in this case you need  a 3th table for relation  .. an user can own more than one PC  .... and constrains as foreign keys are for data integrity  .. performance are based on index .. some constrains  implies  index .. but are different concept  .. take a look  at DB normalization  ..and Indexes ..

Comment: bought_by = user_id

Comment: could be .. but depend  of the system domain you need  to modelling  .. there is not a single solution  .., each db designa is related  at the part of reality  you want modeling

Comment: I mean if I will write select * from pc where bought_by = 1 , it will be going throught all table to the moment when it will find smth like this (one or many values), but can I make relations where it will not be checking each value , but will be know exactly where this value is ( for example 4, and 444 row in the pc table ) , and I get data fast

Comment: smth like an link when db knows from the start where values with the same id

Comment: the db know how retrive the rows  ( and is very able to do this). For performace you can add  indexes  hat help the db engine for find fastly  the rows  involved ..  some constratins as pk or fk implies the  creation of index  so you must think at th correct design  of the data model and the correct modellig for data integrity respecting the normal form... for performance once the db is poplutaed you can add  some indexes where needed. What you call a link  .. is a normal key .. eventually  (if needed  based on constrains ) and if not provided  by the data constranins .. based  on index

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely create primary and foreign keys for these tables, along with an index on `pc (bought_by)`.

Not only will this speed up join queries that fetch only a few rows, but it will guarantee the integrity of your database. Better safe than sorry.